# An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Tags: python-asyncio

When reading an article on the asyncio module, I wanted to try it in my project. The idea is to wait for a window to disappear.

```py
import asyncio
import pyautogui
import os

workPath = os.getcwd()
filePath = workPath+"\\Projets\\Rotation_PP\\Scripts\\Screenshot\\"

# Wait for the publication to finish. The window should disappear
publicationProgress = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(filePath+'PlanningProgress.png')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(publicationProgress != None)
```

A priori I must do it wrong because I have the following error:

TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Maybe I'm looking for complications and a simple while would be enough.

Could you, please, help me to solve this problem ?

Best regards

Comment: I don't know about pyautogui, but you see this error because you loop.run_until_complete accepts only awaitable object, 'publicationProgress != None' returns boolean

Comment: asyncio is not meant to be used the way you've attempted. You need a library that supports asyncio, for starters. For your use case you might be better served by threads.